# What is the relationship between parallelogram law and polarisation identity?

Tags: linear-algebra

According to wikipedia article on polarisation identity, in a normed space $(V, || . ||$), if the parallelogram law holds, then there is an inner product on V such that $||x||^2 = \langle x, x\rangle$ for all $x \in V$. However, from what I understand, we can prove polarisation identity this way:

$$||x + y||^2 - ||x-y||^2 = \langle x+y, x+y\rangle - \langle x-y, x-y\rangle = ... = 4\langle x,y\rangle$$

However, from this proof, I don't see why we need parallelogram law. On top of that, shouldn't it be the other way round, such that if $||x||^2 = \langle x, x\rangle$, then the parallelogram law holds? Can someone explain to me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the theorem is the existence of the inner product. It is true (and easy to show) that if you are given an inner product $\langle -, -\rangle$ then you can always define a norm via $||x||^2 = \langle x, x\rangle$, and this norm satisfies the parallelogram law and the polarisation identity. But that isn't the situation the theorem is considering. It is about the situation where you start with a norm and want to define an inner product such that $\langle x, x \rangle = ||x||^2$.

If you are just given a norm to start with, you can't necessarily define an inner product from that. Just defining $\langle x, x \rangle = ||x||^2$ doesn't even define $\langle x, y \rangle$ in general, let alone mean that $\langle -, -\rangle$ has the linearity properties you need for the "=" in your equation. Even defining $\langle x, y \rangle = (||x+y||^2 - ||x-y||^2)/4$ doesn't get the linearity properties unless you have the parallelogram law as well.

Comment: Is there a reason why we want to do this? Is there an example of how this is useful?

Comment: Can I say that if parallelogram law holds, then $<x,x> = ||x||^2$ if and only if <x,x> satisfies the polarisation identity?

Comment: @user2675516 Parallelogram law <=> can define $\langle x, x\rangle$ such that $\langle x, x\rangle = ||x||^2$ and polarisation identity holds.

Comment: The parallelogram law is a statement about normed spaces. $\langle x, x\rangle = ||x||^2$ doesn't make sense if you don't have an inner product defined.